# How to query pandas dataframe for regular expression?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df:

```
{'col1': {0: 'vJAaIAM',
  1: 'K0jQAF',
  2: '00qvP1IIU',
  3: 'tFCJ2',
  4: '0d2fIAB'},
 'col2': {0: 6294.0,
  1: 859485.0,
  2: 7362.0,
  3: 6273921.0,
  4: 114506.0}}
```

and I am looking to query this dataframe for all rows that have capital 'A' and here is what I have:

```
df[df['col1']==r'+%[A]%+']
```

I'm not needing to replace these values, I simply want to list and see them.

Comment: `+%[A]%+` is *not* a valid regular expression. The `+` quantifier can only be applied after a regular expression subpattern.

Comment: this is a duplicate, didn't phrase my question right to find that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`.str.contains('A')`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) here:

```
>>> df[df['col1'].str.contains('A')]
      col1      col2
0  vJAaIAM    6294.0
1   K0jQAF  859485.0
4  0d2fIAB  114506.0
```